# Register callback to afterOnCellMouseDown event with rhandsontable

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, handsontable, rhandsontable

I have an rhandsontable and wish to trigger an event each time a cell is clicked, such that I can identify the cell which was clicked.

From what I've seen, this can only be done using JS.

I've tried using the basic `.click()` event, but that uses an argument-free function and `this` is the HTML itself, with no "selectedCell" property or what have you.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("redraw", "Redraw"),
  rHandsontableOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$test <- renderRHandsontable({
    input$redraw  # force re-rendering if desired
    
    runjs("$('#test').click(function() {
          console.log(this)
    });")
    
    rhandsontable(data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 3:4))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Looking at the handsontable documentation, I've found the [`afterOnCellMouseDown` event](https://handsontable.com/docs/8.4.0/Hooks.html#event:afterOnCellMouseDown), which seems adequate for my use-case, taking a function with a `coords` argument which informs me of the selected cell. I should be able to use this in conjunction with `Shiny.onInputChange` to let my app identify the clicked cell.

However, I can't figure out the JS I need to run to bind to the `afterOnCellMouseDown` event. As I mentioned, using `$('#test')` gives me the HTML and I don't know how to access the `hot` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the app below, the coordinates of the clicked cell are sent to `input$clickedCell`, a list of the form `list(row = i, col = j)`.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(htmlwidgets)

jsCode <- c(
  "function(el, x) {",
  "  Handsontable.hooks.add('afterOnCellMouseDown', function(event, coords, TD){",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('clickedCell', coords, {priority: 'event'});",
  "  });",
  "}"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$test <- renderRHandsontable({    
    rhandsontable(data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 3:4)) %>% onRender(jsCode)
  })
  observe({print(input$clickedCell)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is applied to all `handsontable` instances of the app. I don't know how to target a specific one (I think this is not possible).

Comment: Excellent answer! My real use-case actually uses multiple rhandsontables and this binds to every single one. However, after a quick Google I realized that I just have to make a slight edit to the JS code: ```Handsontable.hooks.add('after[...]', function([...]) {[...]}, this.hot)```. I'll wait the customary 24 hours, but expect a checkmark soon!